# Сравнение объектов класса ImageIcon

Tags: java

подскажите каким образом можно сравнить два объекта класса ImageIcon и получить true если в них помещена одна и та же картинка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсчитывайте hash файлов, и сравнивайте их

Comment: Они грузятся не из файла, одна является байтовым клоном второй, задача программы узнать изменялась ли картинка.

Answer (score 0):

Решил так

```
If (image1.toString.hashCode()!=(image2.toString.hashCode()) return false;
```

Comment: Хотя теоретически если разные картинки из файлов с одинаковым именем то не сработает.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/428008)

Comment: @BasilJimmy это явно не дополнение к вопросу, это таки ответ, хоть и короткий